# Supporting dependency of P frame on I frame only

Tags: encoder, x264

I have a doubt on x264 encoding.

If I have IP_1P_2P_3 IPPP some kind of this GOP from the x264 encoded output. Then in general, P_3 will be dependent on I, P_1 and P_2, P_2 will be dependent on I and P_1 (a cumulative encoding).

Can anyone please give me any ideas how can I support direct encoding so that all P_1, P_2, P_3 will be only dependent on the I frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the x264 source code to add references frame invalidation to all non IDR frames.  It’s already a supported and existing function in x264  It just need to be called on the P/B frames.

Comment: Can you please tell me which functions I need to modify? or which exact parameters? if I make      h->i_nal_ref_idc = 0 or i_nal_ref_idc = 0, does it make the P frames independent of I frame?

Comment: No, I will not give you the exact modifications. Just look T the api, and the x264.h. It will be clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. can you please help me telling what i_nal_ref_idc parameter implies? About the encoder_invalidate_reference, it will invalidate a particular frame (especially applicable for frame loss), in that case, the encoder forgets (erase) the frame. But if I invoke invalidate_reference while doing P-frame encoding, then encoder will forget the previous P frames then.